# Starting Mutt on raspberry pi gives errors processing Muttrc

Tags: linux, mutt

I recently apt-get upgraded my pi, running stretch. When I start mutt, it displays the error messages below.

```
Error in /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d, line 3: for: unknown command
Error in /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d, line 4: test: unknown command
Error in /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d, line 5: done: unknown command
Error in /etc/Muttrc, line 147: source: errors in /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d
```

Looking at /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d (below), it seems straightforward. If I run the commands manually (including /bin/sh -e).

```
#!/bin/sh -e

for rc in /etc/Muttrc.d/*.rc; do
    test -r "$rc" && echo "source \"$rc\""
done
```

/etc/Muttrc has:

```
##
# See /usr/share/doc/mutt/README.Debian for details.
source /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d
```

The man page for muttrc has the source command, but it reads it as a configuration file, not an os script. The man page doesn't say anything about the test keyword, or any indication of running a shell script from the configuration file.

What needs to be done to process the Muttrc.d files correctly?

```
mutt -v
NeoMutt 20170113 (1.7.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error (for whatever reason) in your `/etc/Muttrc`. On my `stretch`-box the lines read:

```
source /usr/lib/mutt/source-muttrc.d|
```

The `|` at the end of the line is important. In the [Mutt-manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/) we read in Sect. 27:

> If the filename ends with a vertical bar (“|”), then filename is considered to be an executable program from which to read input (e.g. source ~/bin/myscript|).

For some reason even the `muttrc` manpage in Version 1.10.1 does not document the feature, but the corresponding  [manpage from neomutt](https://neomutt.org/man/neomuttrc) does.

Comment: Great. I did end up with another error now - but easily resolved from this [neomutt page](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/398) by initially setting to no, but then just installing the gpgsm package